# Adding an <img> to Form Builder (Afform) aff.html

Tags: forms, images, formbuilder

I'd like to add an image via the aff.html file that is generated when a Form Builder/Afform form is made. (I am using a local testing version of civiCRM via buildkit)

Tried linking an image from the web as the string for the `src=""` property in the `<img />` tag.

Also tried saving the downloaded image within the directory of the aff.html file and setting the `src=""` to the image's path:
 `<img src="./images/signup.png" alt="Sign up to be the first to know!"/>`

The alt text is displayed when I select "View Page" from Form Builder, but the image never loads despite receiving a 200 OK status for the image from the Networks tab in the Dev Tools panel.

I know that where an image file is saved and accessed from in a file structure can be a bit picky. Has anyone managed to add an image to their aff.html file, and if so:

1. Which of the two methods above did you use?
2. If the second method, what is the proper storage place within the buildkit... web/sites/default/civicrm/ang file structure?